# failed to Implementing google adsense in my android app

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I signed to adsense and got my id to use adsense mechanism. I followed the tutorial http://code.google.com/intl/iw/mobile/afma_ads/docs/android/ and did exactly like the incomprehensible tutorial (Very surprising). Also the jar file that i supposed to add to my libs not available in the site and i downloaded it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/DownloadGoogleAdViewjar.htm. When i load my app i get a banner filled with "AD TEST" strings. When i tried to change the boolean parameter in setAdTestEnabled to false i got empty banner (not visible).

Does anyone run into such behavior using adsense?

Does anyone know better tutorial?

Does AdMob and Adsense connected to google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the test ad worked it could be that you have either not set your unique ID in **your** adWords account or its just not been activated yet therefor there are no images to retrieve.

Another reason could be that the image that it did retrieve doesnt fit into the view you have gave it. Something like that should throw an exception so have a look through your code in debug and see if it does throw an error

Comment: Why do i need to set unique id in adWords? adwords used to display ads on Google (am i wrong?) and i'm trying to draw ads. 
Also i used the component from the sample program so i don't think it relevantin this case. 
Tnx chris

Comment: Um for you to get paid you will have to make sure you but your ID in

Comment: Also you may as well just implement Admob as that can also run off adsense

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at an old old version of the Ads SDK.  The download link probably isn't on the site anymore because it is now recommended/required to use the [Google AdMob Ads SDK](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/).  It is a rewrite of the Google Ads SDK, and it has active support and documentation.  I recommend trying it out, and any questions you may have you can ask on the [support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk).

Side Note: I say using the new SDK is required because if you read through the the documentation, you will find a warning saying all new sites and apps created after October 14th, 2011 have to use the Google AdMob Ads SDK.